# How to arrange multiple images horizontally on single activity

Tags: android, image, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I am new to android i have developed an application in which i have to display images horizontal view on single activity i have done using staggered recycleview   but am getting like this.

[image]

But i want to design like this as part of the activity.

[image]

Comment: please paste code

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Pradeep Kumar i have done remaining part of design only thing is i am not able to display the asked question

Comment: use a custom layoutmanager for your RecyclerView to showitems as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that with [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager). Use [SpanSizeLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup) to control your row/column . For your case you have to use `HORIZONTAL` orientation. `SpanSizeLookup` will help you to control your rows in each column in `HORIZONTAL` `GridLayoutManager`.

```
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), NUM_OF_ROW, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, reverseOrder);

    GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup spanSizeLookup = new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
              // for position 0 use only one row. for this position it will take all rows
            if (position  == 0) {
                 return NUM_OF_ROW;
            }

            return 1;
        }
};
```

[Here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/07/set-spansizelookup-to-gridlayoutmanager.html) is blog post about different Layout Manager implementation.

I have uploaded a [repo](https://github.com/yousufshawon/AdvanceRecyclerView) on Github about different LayoutManager usage like [LinearLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager), [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager), [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager) and some advance RecyclerView usage like swipe, Drag and Drop. You can also check that

Answer (score 0):

here is what i use for arranging items horizontally provided you're using RecyclerView:

```
 int numberOfColumns = 3; //edit as you want pls
        final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), numberOfColumns);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I might be off your solution, perdon if so, but pasting some of your code might help better.

Comment: StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recyclerViewStaggered.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);

        StaggeredAdapter customAdapter = new StaggeredAdapter(getActivity(), personImages);
        recyclerViewStaggered.setAdapter(customAdapter);

Comment: If orientation is vertical, spanCount is number of columns.                                                                                                                  If orientation is horizontal, spanCount is number of rows.                                         I don't think you notice this??? Apparently your code is set! and this all you need to do: change HORIZONTAL to VERTICAL

Comment: What about span count then? shall i use it or not

Comment: yes you need span count! it helps set how many pictures will be displayed in columns after which the rest of the pictures will go to the next row.